# Ember data 0.13 to 0.14 - no stateManager property on records?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I tried to upgrade an application from Ember data 0.13 to **0.14**.

I have some

```
record.get('stateManager').goToState('updated');
```

statements in my code.

It seems though that the `stateManager` property is gone. I found the `currentState` property.

How can I manually change / manipulate a record's state in Ember data 0.14?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
record.transitionTo('updated.uncommitted');
```

does the trick.